# Dynamic CButton margin

Tags: button, visual-c++, mfc

I am using this code to set the initial size of my buttons:

```
// Now check button sizes
auto *pDC = m_btnPreview.GetDC();
if (pDC != nullptr)
{
    pDC->SelectObject(GetFont());
    auto sizeActualSize = pDC->GetTextExtent(strButtonText);
    sizeActualSize.cx += 10;
    if (sizeActualSize.cx > rctOK.Width())
    {
        // We need to consistently resize both buttons
        int iButtonGap = rctCancel.left - rctOK.right;

        rctCancel.left = rctCancel.right - sizeActualSize.cx;
        rctOK.right = rctCancel.left - iButtonGap;
        rctOK.left = rctOK.right - sizeActualSize.cx;

        GetDlgItem(IDOK)->MoveWindow(rctCancel);
        m_btnPreview.MoveWindow(rctOK);
    }

    ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

It works fine. I correctly set the font so that the size returned is right. But I have added a value of 10 to pad it a bit so that the button looks nicer:

[image: Moved button]

Is there a specific MFC constant for the default gap around button? Rather than fudging it with a value of 10?

Comment: [`CButton::GetIdealSize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class?view=vs-2017#getidealsize) is propably better suitable and should take any padding defined by the theme into account. That is way better than hardcoding a magic constant (without even DPI-scaling it).

Comment: @zett42 I did not know about this! I will try it soon.

Comment: @zett42 Worked well, thanks.